# If $A^3 = A$ then the eigen values are all 1 right?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, diagonalization

Since $A^n = PD^nP^{-1}$ where D is a matrix consisting only of the eigenvalues of   on its leading diagonal. For the scenario to be true $D^B = D$ which is only true if the eigenvalues are all 1s (not 0s as i think that maybe against the rules, is it?)

Comment: No. For example if $A=0$, all eigenvalues are $0$.

Comment: Are all the entries real or can they be complex?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess the only thing you can say is that the eigenvalues all satisfy the equation $x^3=x$...

Comment: Oh ok so the eigen values are any that satisfy $\lambda = \sqrt[3]{x}$

Comment: No, of course not ;) it is 0 or $\pm 1$

Comment: but wouldn't 2^3 and 4^3 and 5^3 etc satisfy the equation too?

Comment: Your number has to be a solution of $x^3-x=0$...

Comment: oh lol so $x(x^2-1)=0$ ---> $x(x-1)(x+1)$  x=0 or 1 or -1

Answer (score 1):

take 
$$A = -I.$$
then
$$
A^3 = A.
$$
More generally, take a diagonal matrix with all entries $1, -1$ or $0$ and the equation is satisfied. 
The eigenvalues will have to from that set however.